# Copy content from some other word file into currently active word document without opening the other word file

Tags: c#, office-interop

I am creating an Add In for Microsoft Word and I have an active document open in my Word Application object.

```
using tw = Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word;
using w = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using wp = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

tw.Document doc = 
Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument);
```

I need to copy some content from another word document file into this `doc` object at current cursor position, without opening that source document file.

> Update:-

By saying, without opening the source file, I am making a work around for me, and yes, that means, I don't want to show that source file open in MS Word - with a Word Method that will do this automatically if it exist, without making a hack of opening the Source Word file invisibly.

Originally, what I need is - I have that source file saved as a Binary Object (`BLOB`) in my database, and would like to load it directly in a `MemoryStream` and copy contents from it to the `Active Word Document`. But, because I am not getting a way to do this, I thought I will save that source file temporarily on the disk, and then copy its contents into the active document, provided it is not visible in the MS Word while copying.

Is this possible?

Any API available for doing this?

Comment: Can you please add some clarification (possibly in the title as well)?  Are you wanting to copy content from some other file into the currently active document, or copy content from the currently active document to some other document?

Comment: Define "open". If you mean "read file contents from the disk", it's not possible. If you mean "without showing another instance of MS Word", then it's possible.

Comment: Do you need to support the older (pre-Word 2007) .doc format, or just the newer .docx format?

Comment: Just the .docx format.

Comment: You may consider using the Open XML SDK. See [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.